# Is there a solution to stop converting months data from number to alphabetics in java program?

Tags: java, csv, simpledateformat

I'am working on reading data from csv file, I'am at the point of reading time data. The data in the csv is written in this way 5/15/2020  10:00:00 AM but when I read I get this : 15/Apr/2020. This is a snippet of what I tried until now.

```
String dateClosedBug = csvToObjects[1].toString();
String[] splitDateClosedBug = dateClosedBug.split(" ");
                    
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date closedDate = dateFormat.parse(splitDateClosedBug[0]);
System.out.println(closedDate);
```

`csvToObjects[1]` is a variable of another treatment. I cannot print the value of closedDate because there is an error in parsing the value. Does anyone have an idea of what should I change in my approach in parsing the value?

Comment: Short answer is: **There is a solution** :)

Comment: That's funny ! that would be awesome if you guide me on this one on where to head to find this solution :)

Comment: As they say, most of the time the answer is hidden in the question. And [a hint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Dont hesitate to keep asking questions(even better - clarify the question itself, fix the title, etc). Also consider adding current output/desired output, as we have no idea what is your issue...

Comment: Change the format to `M/d/yyyy`

Comment: I recommend you switch from the outdated and error-prone `java.util` date-time API and `SimpleDateFormat` to the [modern](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) `java.time` date-time API and the corresponding formatting API (package, `java.time.format`). Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Is there a reason for you not to use `java.time` for parsing and formatting date and time values? It's strongly recommended as @ArvindKumarAvinash already commented.

Comment: No there is not specific reason for not using ````java.time```` @deHaar, that's why i'am going to exploit this solution more. Thank you

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I get `Fri Mar 05 00:00:00 CET 2021` (which is not correct, though).

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work.

```
    DateTimeFormatter csvFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/u h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);
    
    String dateClosedBug = "5/15/2020 10:00:00 AM";
    
    LocalDateTime closedBug = LocalDateTime.parse(dateClosedBug, csvFormatter);
    LocalDate closedBugDate = closedBug.toLocalDate();
    
    System.out.println(closedBugDate);
```

Output from this code snippet is:

> 2020-05-15

Rather than splitting the string I found it both better and easier to parse it in its entirety. It’s easier to throw information away after parsing than to invent information that you neglected to parse.

**Tutorial link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.